# Splitting string between found patterns

Tags: java, string, split

The standard method for splitting string

```
String [] arr = s.split (regex);
```

Cuts the pieces out and removes the found regex. Is the a method that does the opposite?

**NOTE:** In my case there is nothing between the regex

Example:

*Input*

```
s = "320,192,6057,1,0,0:0:0:0:64,192,6327,128,0,7408:0:0:0:0:";
```

*Output*

```
arr[0] = "320,192,6057,1,0,0:0:0:0:";
arr[1] = "64,192,6327,128,0,7408:0:0:0:0:";
```

Comment: What do you call the opposite ? Strictly speaking, the opposite would be to remove all the "pieces" that do not match the regex, is that what you want ?

Comment: The question is unclear, you should just add an input/output example

Comment: @Dici Yes, but for now it doesn't matter if it'll be removed. Updated the Question for this important detail

Comment: What's the point? Just add the separator character back when you output each split. If it's important to not be added to the final element, then check the index isn't `(length() - 1)`.

Comment: @aliteralmind Maybe it was wtong posting a highly simplyfied example. I'll edit that

Answer (score 6):

You can use a positive lookbehind regex to split your string like this:

```
(?<=;)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQ3lC5/1)**

[IdeOne code](http://ideone.com/KCg4FU)

```
String[] arr = "1234:5678;8765,4321;".split("(?<=;)");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
// arr[0] => 1234:5678;
// arr[1] => 8765,4321;
```

The trick of using regex lookaround (a positive lookbehind in this answer) is that lookarounds don't consume characters, therefore you won't lose the `;` you want.

Comment: Sounds like it would work. Did you test it (with split) ?

Comment: @Dici yes, updated it IdeOne online demo

Comment: The sample in the Question was simplyfied. https://regex101.com/r/pT1lA4/2 in this test i use string like ones I'll use in my program. does it work with such regex?

Comment: @risingprogrammer you shouldn't change a question with a complete different meaning since answers get outdated. Imho, you should edit your question back to the original I answered, mark it as resolved and create another question in case you have more doubts.